# Why does DPSK constellation shrink when noise is added?

Tags: noise, digital-communications, modulation, qpsk

I am generating a DQPSK waveform at complex base band with constellation points on the unit circle and when I add AWG noise the constellation shrinks.  The noisy constellation "blob" migrate inside the unit circle.  My question is why is this happening and is it supposed to happen or am I missing something?

My method of adding noise is:

```
Xnoise = X + sigma/2 * (randn(N) + 1j*randn(N))
```

where sigma is the overall standard deviation for the noise.  It's being divided by 2 since I'm using two separate randns for the real and imag parts and the two Gaussians added together give me the correct variance.

[image: Ideal DPSK]

[image: Noisy DPSK Eb/N0=14]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your circle got bigger. The constellation is fine.

Comment: Good call.  I didn't even notice that.  I am using Matplotlib and just plotting a circle of radius 1, but I must be doing something that is causing it to change.